# How to convert a png base64 string to pixel array without using canvas getImageData?

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

Although it seems that this question has been asked before, people rely on canvas for that conversion. The problem is going from a base64 url like this:   `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAFElEQVQIW2NkYGD4D8RYAeOQkgQAERQHAbuZaGoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

to a pixel array with color intensities like this 
`var array  = [ [0x00,0x00,0x00], ... 49 times ];` for a 7px by 7px image (black in that case), we have to use code like this:

```
var mCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var base64DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAFElEQVQIW2NkYGD4D8RYAeOQkgQAERQHAbuZaGoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
mCanvas.width = 7;
mCanvas.height = 7;
var mContext = mCanvas.getContext('2d');
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.setAttribute("src", base64DataUrl);
myImage.onload = function() { 
    var mContext = mCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var mImgData = mContext.getImageData(0,0,mCanvas.width,mCanvas.height);
}
```

which becomes asynchronous because of the *onload* and very painful to work with (although it works).

Then we would use code like this to get the RGBA colors from canvas

```
function convertCanvasToPixelsArray(mCanvas){
    var mContext = mCanvas.getContext('2d');
    console.log(mCanvas.width);
    var mImgData = mContext.getImageData(0,0,mCanvas.width,mCanvas.height);

    var srcIndex=0, dstIndex=0, curPixelNum=0;
    var pixelsArray = new Array(mCanvas.width*mCanvas.height);
    for (curPixelNum=0; curPixelNum<mCanvas.width*mCanvas.height;  curPixelNum++)
    {
        pixelsArray[dstIndex] = new Array(3);
        pixelsArray[dstIndex][0] = mImgData.data[srcIndex]; // r
        pixelsArray[dstIndex][1] = mImgData.data[srcIndex+1];   // g
        pixelsArray[dstIndex][2] = mImgData.data[srcIndex+2];   // b

        dstIndex += 1;
        srcIndex += 4;
    }
    return pixelsArray;
}
```

Is there a way to just convert from the Base64 png image string to an array like the above without canvas? I have tried PNG.js which it says that the png is corrupt or incomplete (and I tried with or without the `data:image/png;base64,`. I have tried most of base64.js and I take bytes that don't make any sense. I tried atob/btoa calls with no relevant results either.

The answer for this question ([Is is possible to read pixel data from base64 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813162/is-is-possible-to-read-pixel-data-from-base64-images?rq=1)) should have been working but I get (just for the new PNG(data) ):

```
Uncaught Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file
```

with my example:

```
function show(data){
        var png = new PNG(data);
        var img = document.getElementById('image'), limg = document.getElementById('largeimage');
        document.getElementById('nativeimage').src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
        img.innerHTML = '';
        limg.innerHTML = '';
        img.style.width = png.width + 'px';
        img.style.height = png.height + 'px';
        limg.style.width = (png.width * 3) + 'px';
        limg.style.width = (png.height * 3) + 'px';
        var line;
        while(line = png.readLine())
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < line.length; x++){
                var px = document.createElement('div'), px2 = document.createElement('div');
                px.className = px2.className = 'pixel';
                px.style.backgroundColor = px2.style.backgroundColor = '#' + line[x].toString(16).padRight('0', 6);
                img.appendChild(px);
                limg.appendChild(px2);
            }
        }
    }


    show("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAFElEQVQIW2NkYGD4D8RYAeOQkgQAERQHAbuZaGoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
```

or the example in that question. I am using this PNG.js: [ I am not using this anymore]
https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/png.js

**EDIT** The two packages are not the same - let's see!

**EDIT 2** it almost worked using this http://jsfiddle.net/6VqwC/8/ from the other question **BUT** if you go you will see my black tile is becoming stripes of **blue,green, red** - is that a bug of the package :/ ?

**EDIT 3** so it seems that the package is working with compressed pngs - and my pngs are not compressed - is there a way to use the PNG.js with non compressed files?

**EDIT 4** So if I make a function (like in the answer that was deleted):

```
function convertBase64ToPixelsArray(tile,whatToDoNext){
        var base64DataUrl = tile.base64DataUrl;
        var mCanvas = newEl("canvas");
        var ctx = mCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var pixelsArray = [];

        var img = newEl("img");
        img.onload = getRGB;
        img.src = base64DataUrl;

        function getRGB(){
            mCanvas.width = img.width;
            mCanvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,mCanvas.width, mCanvas.height).data;
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4){
                pixelsArray.push([data[i],data[i+1],data[i+2]]);
            }
            whatToDoNext(pixelsArray);
        }
    }
```

and have multiple different functions like these:

```
function doSomethingWithTile(tile,params){
   convertBase64ToPixelsArray(tile,function(pixelsArray){
    //manipulate the pixels 
    //convert them back to base64 and store it in the tile
    tile.base64UrlData = convertPixelsArrayToCanvas(pixelsArray,tile.width,tile.height).convertToBase64();
    });
}
```

then when I am doing that

```
var tile = initialize_tile();
doSomethingWithTile(tile,params1);
doSomethingWithTile2(tile,params2);
doSomethingWithTile(tile,params1);
...
```

what happens is that the initial tile is being manipulated so the effects do not accumulate. If you can help me with that then I have an answer that will use canvas. The call queue of doSomethingWithTile is not predefined/static and can be arbitrary

I am really baffled and I would really appreciate your help :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the right starting point for what you ask is to use an XMLHTTPRequest to retrieve the raw data, then decode the file by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. The decoding was way difficult to implement because of various levels of compression etc... So I just did my code asynchronous but with guaranteed order of executions. I haven't touched the code ever since. I've been working on something else..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is is possible to read pixel data from base64 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813162/is-is-possible-to-read-pixel-data-from-base64-images)